# How to build the Ext JS Open Tooling sample app for production? Ext._find not defined

Tags: extjs

Using ext-gen (7.0.2) and creating a sample moderndesktop boilerplate project (Ext JS 7.0.0.156) I run into problems when I try to generate a production build. 
The "lodash.find" npm module added as a demo to the project (in the index.js file) is not included and thus the built production application fails to run.
I am trying to build with `npm run build:desktop` command.

Comment: did you try without the open tooling, but using sencha cmd?

Comment: Yes I did. Since the magic is the index.js file containing the link between the npm package lodash.find and Ext JS it must be included in the production build and I guess it is only open tooling that can handle that.